# Is there any mathematical formula or method to compute the values of Landau function (by hand)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know that the value of [Landau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) $g(n)$ for any natural number $n$ gives us the largest order of an element of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ Namely, $g(n)=\max(\text{ord}(k) \mid \forall k \in S_{n})$. But, this cannot help us compute $g(n)$ for large $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is there any possible mathematical method to compute $g(n), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ ?
Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Yes of course there is! Consider every element of $S_n$ in turn, calculate its order and keep track of the maximum.

Comment: But, how can I keep track of the maximum if the input number is large (like 100)? Is it possible to calculate it by hand?

Comment: I am sorry, but my comment was deliberately silly, because you have not made it clear in your question what you are looking for. You need to calculate the maximum of ${\rm lcm}(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$ for partitions $n=n_1+ \cdots + n_k$ of $n$. It would be hard to do $n=100$ by hand (I have set $n=52$ as a challenge problem for students, which some of them occasionally solve), but easy by computer. I wrote a naive C-program to do this a few years ago, and it works quite quickly up to about $n=25000$, but there are probably better implementations around.

Comment: Excuse me for the confusion and the ambiguity in my question. I will correct it immediately. Thank you for your good point!

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2160) describes a method for computing it that the authors claim works up to $n=10^{15}$.

Edit: I see now that you want to do this by hand, and of course we are talking here about a method intended for a computer. I don't know whether it can easily be done by hand for smaller $n$. I think it differs from earlier methods in that it does not require prior computation of $g(m)$ for all $m<n$.

Answer (score 2):

$g(n)$ is the maximum value of $\text{lcm}(n_1, \dots n_k)$ where $\sum n_i = n$. Suppose some $n_i$ can be written as $n_i = ab$ where $a, b \ge 2$ and $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ (this is possible iff $n_i$ is not a prime power). Then we can contemplate the effect of removing $n_i$ and replacing it by $a$ and $b$. This doesn't affect the lcm but $n_i > a + b$ since

$$(a - 1)(b - 1) \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow ab \ge a + b + 1$$

so the sum has gotten smaller, which means we can now increase the lcm by adding more terms or making other terms larger. If $\{ n_i \}$ is a maximal partition then either this move is impossible or making it does not increase the lcm; either way we can make it WLOG. In other words:

> **Lemma 1:** The maximum value of $\text{lcm}(n_1, \dots n_k)$ is achieved by a partition in which the $n_i$ are all prime powers.

Furthermore suppose $n_i$ and $n_j$ are powers of the same prime, say $n_i = p^a$ and $n_j = p^b$ where $a \ge b$ WLOG. Then we can remove $n_j$ without affecting the lcm, so we can again now increase the lcm by either adding more terms or making other terms larger. So:

> **Lemma 2:** The maximum value of $\text{lcm}(n_1, \dots n_k)$ is achieved by a partition in which the $n_i$ are powers of distinct primes.

This gives us the following "formula" for $g(n)$, which you can find on the [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000793) for Landau's function:

$$\boxed{ g(n) = \text{max} \left\{ \prod p_i^{e_i} : \sum p_i^{e_i} \le n \right\} }$$

(the $\le$ is because we can always pad with $1$s). This is still an optimization problem but over a smaller set than initially (over what we might call the prime-power-partitions of $n$), and involving a product instead of an lcm which is easier to understand the behavior of.

As an application I believe that $g(52) = 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 = 180180$ but the strategy I had in mind for writing down a proof by hand got very complicated and involved bounding and computing several smaller values of $g$.

Comment: Yes, 180180 looks familiar!